# Should I read googleads.yaml file for every request?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I've been testing [Python Google AdWords Library](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/targeting) and every example does authentication the same way, reading the googleads.yaml (taking 15-20 seconds) which is horribly slow. I read that there's a caching alternative but I still don't understand how to do it. How can I create a client, initialize it at the start of the application, only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have initialized your `adwords.AdWordsClient` instance using the `LoadFromStorage()` constructor, you can keep it for however long you want. It will refresh the provided access token on its own when required.

Having said that, reading the yaml file and obtaining the initial access token should take nowhere near 15 seconds. Are you sure the code is not blocking elsewhere?